# Problem with accents and special characters in document, using Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: accents

I am writing a series of documents, that I want to show the best look I can get. In the process, I found an amazing template, that of course I would like to use with those documents.

From the very start, I was in trouble. I made a lot of investigation, but I cannot solve my problem with the accents, that not show in the final PDF. Of course, I get lot of errors in the compilation process.

The curious fact is that in the titles (index, chapter, subchapter, and so on) the accents look grood. But, in the text, te text show with no accents and special characters.

I got the template as is. In fact, the only change I made to the template is the language, that is

```
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
```

for

```
 \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

In my opinion, the error that show my problem is

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:éri not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
```

but I don't know how can I solve it.

Comment: But I already have

  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

in my document

Comment: But the text don't show accents, and titles yes.

Comment: Cause the apported solutions doesn't fix my problem, I've been investigating, and I have seen that if I included all the text in the main document, without separating files, and --because of that-- I don't use the \input or \include commands, the PDF shows fine and well. Now is when I don't understand...